# using toArray with ArrayList of custom objects

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Is there a way to use the `toArray()` method on an `ArrayList<CustomObject>`?

From what I see, it can only be used with `Object`

Comment: There is `ArrayList<T>.toArray()`...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to pass in an array of `CustomObject` in order to get one back. The parameter-free `ArrayList.toArray()` call returns an `Object[]`, but the parameterized version [`T[] ArrayList<T>.toArray(T[])`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29) returns what you expect. If you size the array you pass as a parameter correctly then the call will use the array you pass rather than allocate another one, e.g.

```
ArrayList<CustomObject> foo;
//...
CustomObject[] bar = foo.toArray(new CustomObject[foo.size()]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
CustomObject[] customObjects = myList.toArray(new CustomObject[myList.size()])
```

Answer (score 0):

CustomObj[] customArray = new CustomObj[size];

customArray = (CustomObj[])ArrayListObj.toArray(customArray);